# Excluding Everything in /Library/ but /Library/Mail via rsync

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting, rsync

I have an rsync script that backs up user's home folder using this line of code:

```
/usr/bin/caffeinate -i /usr/bin/rsync -rlptDn --human-readable --progress --ignore-existing --update $PATH/$NAME/ --exclude=".*" --exclude="Public" --exclude="Library" /Volumes/Backup/Users/$NAME\ -\ $DATE
```

How do I ignore everything in `~/Library/` but their `~/Library/Mail/`? I wanted to include this `rsync` flag, `--include="/Library/Mail"`, but I'm not sure if I should depend too much on `rsync` exclusions & inclusions as it can become unreliable and varies between different versions of OS X rsync.

Maybe a command-line regex tool would be more useful? Example:

```
ls -d1 ~/Library/*| grep -v '^mail' > $ALIST
exec <${ALIST}
read SRC
do
.
.
.
$RSYNC..etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync's `--include` and `--exclude` options obey what is called "precedence" so there's a firm rule you can rely which means what you explicitly include before you exclude will be what is sent.

In your case, add `--include ~/Library/Mail` *before* the first `--exclude`.